# Will the partition be hit in an inner Union?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the followning SQL statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT eu_dupcheck AS dupcheck
        , eu_date AS threshold
    FROM WF_EU_EVENT_UNPROCESSED
    WHERE eu_dupcheck IS NOT NULL
    UNION
    SELECT he_dupcheck AS dupcheck
        , he_date AS threshold
    FROM WF_HE_HISTORY_EVENT
    WHERE he_dupcheck IS NOT NULL
)
WHERE threshold > sysdate - 30
```

The second table is partitioned by date but the first isn't. I need to know if the partition of the second table will be hit in this query, or will it do a full table scan?

Comment: Just move the condition into the subqueries.  Then you'll ensure that only the right partitions are used.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, isn't that done by the optimizer already? (And, vice versa, does moving the condition into the sub-queries make sure the right partitions are used?)

Comment: What happens in your tests?

Comment: @jarlh . . . You are probably right that it does.  I'm pretty sure Oracle will do that for `union all`, I'm just wondering if there is an issue caused by duplicate elimination with `union`.

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if Oracle were smart enough to avoid a full table scan.  Remember that `UNION` processes the data by removing duplicates.  So, Oracle would have to recognize that:

- The `where` clause is appropriate for the partitioning (this is actually easy).
- That partitioning does not affect the duplicate removal (this is a bit harder, but true because the date is in the `select`).

Oracle has a smart optimizer, so perhaps it can recognize this situation (and it would probably avoid the full table scan for a `UNION ALL`).  However, you are safer by moving the condition to the subqueries:

```
SELECT *
FROM ((SELECT eu_dupcheck AS dupcheck, eu_date AS threshold
       FROM WF_EU_EVENT_UNPROCESSED
       WHERE eu_dupcheck IS NOT NULL AND eu_date > sysdate - 30
      ) UNION
      (SELECT he_dupcheck AS dupcheck, he_date AS threshold
       FROM WF_HE_HISTORY_EVENT
       WHERE he_dupcheck IS NOT NULL AND he_date > sysdate - 30
      )
     ) eh;
```